# array_map w/ null value

Tags: php, arrays

I use the following to take an array called `$list` and turn it into URLs:

```
function genIMG($sValue) {
return 'http://asite.com/'.$sValue.'?&fmt=jpg';
}
$IMGurls = array_map("genIMG", array_unique($list));
foreach($IMGurls as $imgLink) {
echo "<a href='". $imgLink ."'>". $imgLink ."</a><br />";
}
```

This works, but I also have some `null` values in the array.  How can I have the array map ignore any values of null?  Otherwise it just creates something like this:
`http://asite.com/?&fmt=jpg` with no file name since it was null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You `$list` must have contained empty values use `array_filter`

```
    $IMGurls = array_map("genIMG", array_unique(array_filter($list)));
```

Example

```
$list = array(1,2,3,4,5,"","",7);

function genIMG($sValue) {
    return 'http://asite.com/' . $sValue . '?&fmt=jpg';
}

$IMGurls = array_map("genIMG", array_unique(array_filter($list)));
foreach ( $IMGurls as $imgLink ) {
    echo "<a href='" . $imgLink . "'>" . $imgLink . "</a><br />";
}
```

Output

```
http://asite.com/1?&fmt=jpg
http://asite.com/2?&fmt=jpg
http://asite.com/3?&fmt=jpg
http://asite.com/4?&fmt=jpg
http://asite.com/5?&fmt=jpg
http://asite.com/7?&fmt=jpg
```